# Adding xts objects in a loop

Tags: r, merge, xts

I have a function ugmfit that returns an xts object.
Now I want to write a function out_of_sample_f that contains a loop. In that loop in each iteration fit$est_vol_oos gives an xts with unique dates. I want to add them all together, so that out_of_sample_f can return one xts of all the forecasts

How do I iteratively merge these xts in that loop so that out_of_sample_f returns just one xts object? I don't know if what I am doing is correct? I am thinking by initializing oosf in the beginning maybe something with the dates doesn't work out.

```
out_of_sample_f <- function(rtrn, r_w, re_est_w, exog) {


  oosf = xts(as.numeric(0), as.Date("2013-04-08"))
  
  for (i in 0:(length(rtrn) - r_w)) {
    if(i%%re_est_w == 0){
      mv_m<-mv_into_mat(rtrn[(i + 1):(i + r_w)],exog,K=12,"monthly")
      fit<-ugmfit(model="GM",skew="NO",distribution="norm",rtrn[(i + 1):(i+r_w)],mv_m,K=12, out_of_sample = re_est_w)
      oosf = c(oosf, fit$est_vol_oos)

    }
  }
  oosf <- oosf[-1,]


  return(oosf)
}
```

fit$est_vol_oos is the xts for a particular window. I want to iterate through my data and consecutively add my forecasts.

Later on I use this "merged" xts for something else where differences between this xts and another one are built but I get the error that the two arrays are non conformable.
Edit:
I later use this xts form out_of_sample_f and a original return series as input for yet another function. There it says:
Error in `*.default`((tau - dummies), (realized - evaluated)) :
non-conformable arrays

where realized is the original return series and evaluated is the xts from out_of_sample_f.

Comment: Not clear still.  Do you want `Reduce("+", lst1)`

Comment: Sorry, for asking lot of questions.  If you have created a reprouducible example with clear expected output, we shouldn't have to ask for clarity

Comment: Ok, lets say a is a xts with date "2021-07-19" and just one column that contains a number and b  xts with date "2021-07-20"  and also just one column. Now I want to add a and b together so that the new xts object contains two rows, those of a and b

Comment: The `add` I guess didn't mean the literal adding (`+`) based on the dates, right.  what if there are common dates among those objects.  Do you sum it or keep only the first date row

Comment: If you have dates that are common, what should it return (because xts wouldn't allow duplicate index)

Comment: There aren't  going to be common dates.

Comment: A reproducible example includes the input and all library statements. See top of [tag:r] tag page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we want to `rbind` from a `list`, use

```
do.call(rbind, lst1)
```

where `lst1` is the output from the `out_of_sample_f` stored in a `list`

---

In the OP's code, there is a line

```
oosf = c(oosf, fit$est_vol_oos)
```

which would be

```
oosf = rbind(oosf, fit$est_vol_oos)
```

```
out_of_sample_f <- function(rtrn, r_w, re_est_w, exog) {


  oosf = xts(as.numeric(0), as.Date("2013-04-08"))
  
  for (i in 0:(length(rtrn) - r_w)) {
    if(i%%re_est_w == 0){
      mv_m<-mv_into_mat(rtrn[(i + 1):(i + r_w)],exog,K=12,"monthly")
      fit<-ugmfit(model="GM",skew="NO",distribution="norm",rtrn[(i + 1):(i+r_w)],mv_m,K=12, out_of_sample = re_est_w)
      oosf = rbind(oosf, fit$est_vol_oos)

    }
  }
  oosf <- oosf[-1,]


  return(oosf)
}
```

Comment: So instead of  oosf = c(oosf, fit$est_vol_oos), I append fit$est_vol_oos to a list in each iteration? How do I append to a list? So I initiate oosf = list()?

Comment: @JohannesHeß If you are already doing this instead of `c`, use `oosf <- rbind(oosf, ..`

Comment: how is rbind different from c?

Comment: @JohannesHeß With matrix output, `c` removes the `dim` attributes, while `rbind` doesn't. i.e. `c(matrix(1:10, 2, 5))#
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10`

Comment: I am still having trouble. I edited the end of my original question.

Comment: @JohannesHeß the issue is we don't have a reproducible example to test and rectify

Comment: I load a lot of data locally from my computer, I don't know how to supply that here.

Comment: @JohannesHeß Sorry, we don't need full data.  Just wanted to see a small example of how you are executing and what should be the output from that.  In your post, it is just the function provided and there is not much info about the arguments supplied or executed

Comment: @JohannesHeß yes, that is your initial input, I just wanted to see a small exxample  with the output of your function

Comment: Do I have to initiate this: oosf = xts(as.numeric(0), as.Date("2013-04-08")) or is there a way to maybe append the fit$est_vol_oos to a list in the loop and rbind the entire list after the loop?

Comment: @JohannesHeß You may create a NULL `list` of length equal to the loooped length and then assign as well, but in that case the loop should start from 1 and not 0 as `R` indexing starts from 1 i..e `oosf <- vector('list', yourlength)` then you may do in the loop `oosf[[i]] <- fit$est_vol_oos` and outside the loop, it is `do.call(rbind, oosf)`

Comment: I think the issue would be that you are creating a initialization as a 0 value of 1 row, which is not needed

Comment: is there a way not to specify the length of the list in advance so that I can just append it in each iteration?

Comment: @JohannesHeß Maybe you culd initiate as `oosf <- NULL` and then you use `oosf <- rbind(oosf, fit$est_vol_oos)` within the loop

Comment: I think that just worked! Thank you so much akrun  :-)